# How do I change the number warnings color in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Those circle thingys with numbers to warn you of changes made that are unsaved on the left sidebar. How do I change their color?

Comment: because it is a themed color, find the color name and customize it, there are a finite number of theme colors, it is called a **badge**

Comment: yep, edited the json. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: do the customize in `settings.json` not in the extension, after an update your edits are gone

Comment: I tried. It wouldn't accept any of the scopes I tried to use inside textMateRules

Comment: these badge colors have nothing to do with TextMate Rules, they are workspace colors